# is there a way to get the count of conflicts while using Django ...bulk_create(.., ignore_conflicts=True)?

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I am using **bulk_create** to upload some data from excel to django db. Since the data is huge I had to use bulk_create instead of **.create** and **.save**. But the problem is that I need to show the user how many duplicate data has been found and has not been uploaded due to integrity error. Is there a way to get the number of errors or duplicate data while using bulk upload?

Answer (score -4):

After, Reading data from csv file.

First **create a list** before inserting data to system.
Then convert that **list to set** after then again sort the data which is in set.
Here , you gets every data exactly one time in sorted manner.

Comment: The number of records are around 36,000. It might create performance issues. That is the only reason I am using bulk_create.

Comment: I have deal with 20000 data , just it takes 1 to 1.5 minutes to insert 20000 data.
Just try out and find the time required.